# Regex pattern to match anything between /* and */ in js

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string with contents like this:

```
/*         
    <h1>some text</h1>             
    <div>more stuff $${}{} etc </div>        
*/
```

I'm trying to get everything between `/*` and `*/`

Currently:

```
 string.match(/[^\/\*](.*)[(\*\/)$]/g);
```

Why doesn't this regex work?

Comment: `.` doesn't match linebreaks

Comment: I'm just curious, but why do you have a string with HTML that is commented out with css/js comments ?

Comment: WTH is `(\*\/)$` inside a character class?

Comment: @adeneo i'm using function.prototype.toString() to create a simple html templating system.

Comment: That seems wildly inappropriate, but have fun!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `.` does not match line breaks. Try this instead:

```
string.match(/\/\*([\s\S]*?)\*\//g);
```

I also made the `*` ungreedy otherwise the first `/*` and last `*/` would be matched. I.e., the entire input:

```
/*         
    <h1>some text</h1>             
    <div>more stuff $${}{} etc </div>        
*/
var somethingImportant = 42;
/*         
    ...     
*/
```

Realize that you will goof up on input like this though:

```
var s = " ... /* ... ";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[(\*\/)$]
```

This tells the regular expression to match any of these characters:

- `(`
- `*`
- `/`
- `)`
- `$`

The first character class is similar.

I don’t really know what you were going for there, but this should work:

```
/\/\*([\s\S]*?)\*\//
```

`\/\*` matches `/*`; the group matches any number of anything, but as little of it as possible (`[\s\S]` becase `.` won’t match newlines in JavaScript and there isn’t an option); and `\*\/` matches `*/`.

Enjoy trying this out with `'/* strings'`, `/regular expressions/*5`, `// inline comments /*`, and `<!-- other inline comments /*`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `\/\*((?:[^*]|(?:\*(?=[^\/])))*)`

The result should be on the first match group.

In languages with zero length look behind (**JavaScript does not support this**) this should work:

```
(?<=\/\*)(?:[^*]|(?:\*(?=[^\/])))*
```

Basically it looks for anything after /* which is either not a * or a * not followed by '/' up until the first */

Comment: thanks for the answer david, but Barts pattern seems to be working alright for now.

Comment: David, FYI: JavaScript does not support `(?<=\/\*)` (look behinds). Your answer suggests you know this, but that might not be known to people reading for an answer to their question in this Q&A.

Comment: Thanks Bart, this is why I wrote the first regex that should work in JavaScript and stated that the second will only work in a language with zero length look behind :)  In any case I think the solution you wrote using the ungreedy match is more elegant.